# Perl, multiple active CPAN-modules possible

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

I updated a CPAN-Module (the old one I used was 2 years old) and after that my software got a problem with the new one.
Because it is in productive state I installed the old version again and all was fine.
But I need some functions from the new available module for new software-features.

So ... Is it possible to have both version of one module active and adress them in a way (e.g. with the version) in perl??

Because it is something about network I can not try the new module on a new computer because of firewalls that only allow the one productive server to access the remote computer.

Thanks for help!
Chris

Comment: Have you ontacted the author? He might be willing to fix the problem in the HEAD.

Comment: If you told us what the module is and what problems it introduces, then we might be able to be more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl 6 has the ability to load multiple versions of the same module side-by-side, and use them as desired. But as you've not specified a Perl version, I shall assume 5.x.

The answer is no. You can certainly install them both (using something like local::lib to put them in different library directories), but you cannot use them both in the same process, because they'll stomp on each others' namespaces.

One solution might be to install the new version, download a copy of the old version, and go through the source carefully to rename it so that it has a completely different name, say, `Foo::Bar` -> `Foo::Bar::Compat`. Then you can load and use both because they'll have different names.

Comment: It's less the helpful, and perhaps harmful, to refer to another language with a similar name that the person can't use. The sort of person who will ask this question will now think they just need to upgrade Perl, which is far from the truth.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do what you want in Perl 5.

The best solution is to install the new version of the module on your test server, run your test suite and fix the problems that the new version of module reveals.

If you don't have a test server or a test suite then you shouldn't be doing any maintenance on your production application until you have both of these things set up.

If there is anything preventing you from setting up a test server and a writing a test suite then my best advice is to find yourself a new job.

Comment: The problem is not a 2nd server but the fact that only the primary is allowed to access the remote machine.

Comment: Then get that fixed. You can't expect to do good work in a broken environment.